# main thread is waiting on sqlcipher cursor close

Tags: android, multithreading, android-contentprovider, sqlcipher

In my app we are doing applyBatch for around 2000 records in worker thread.

at the same time if i rotate the screen i am getting black screen.

> "main@6280" prio=5 waiting
>     java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
>        blocks main@6280
>         at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
>         at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
>         - locked <0x18c5> (a java.lang.Object)
>         at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
>         at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
>         at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:810)
>         at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:844)
>         at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1173)
>         at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$FairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:196)
>         at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:257)
>         at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.lock(SQLiteDatabase.java:490)
>         at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteProgram.close(SQLiteProgram.java:294)
>         at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteQuery.close(SQLiteQuery.java:136)
>         at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCursor.close(SQLiteCursor.java:510)
>         at android.database.CursorWrapper.close(CursorWrapper.java:50)
>         at android.database.CursorWrapper.close(CursorWrapper.java:50)
>         at android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner.close(ContentResolver.java:2512)
>         at android.database.CursorWrapper.close(CursorWrapper.java:50)

I have tried withYieldAllowed but no luck.
Any idea why main thread is waiting for cursor close and any solution for this porblem?

Answer (score 1):

```
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$FairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:196) 
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:257) at
```

debug and check which thread holds lock and why u got deadlock

when u do a db operation:

- which thread is making db operations ?
- are u using for that content provider or db helper ?
- are u locking db or do u use some libs for it ?
- do u use cursor loader ? if so do u call any method within which manipulates on activity thread?

**No lock on ReentrantLock**

[image: Without lock]

**ReentrantLock locked  for write by main thread**

[image: With lock from main thread]

> **to build an android app essentially you need to have a knowledge about concurrency, synchronization, locks:**

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/liveness.html

start digging from there:
**net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.lock(SQLiteDatabase.java:490)**

- try batch transaction up into several smaller transactions
- try to periodically execute SQLiteDatabase#yieldIfContendedSafely() to temporarily release the lock during long update transaction.
- try disable the locks by calling SQLiteDatabase::setLockingEnabled(false) -  that should disable Reentrant lock

Do you  have this  issue both on dalvik and art?

Comment: applyBatch we are doing in a separate thread. we are not doing any locking but i think sqlcipher is doing some locking/unlocking